# CakePHP model named 'Model' not working

Tags: cakephp

I have a model named `Model`. After some frustration with its responses, I came to the conclusion that the class file is not being used.

To test this, I changed the name of the file from `model.php` to `model_x.php` and no errors were encountered.

Can someone verify to me if `Model` is an invalid name for an `appModel class`?

I am using `CakePHP 2.x`

Lee

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The class `Model` is already taken](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Model.html)

So what you should do is create another name. It's the same when using a controller and model named `layout`, because the Layout folder in `View` is already used for the layouts. So you should either come up with a clever solution with routing, or simply give it a different name.